# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() with multiple select

Tags: php, arrays, select, foreach

I have a html form which has a select list box from which you can select multiple values because its multiple property is set to multiple.

```
    <label>¿Quieres agregar complementos?</label><hr>

    <?php
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM complementos";
       $ejecutar = $conn->query($sql);
    ?>

    <select class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" name="complementos" data-placeholder="Seleccione el/los complementos" style="width: 100%;">

        <?php while ($complemento = $ejecutar->fetch_assoc()): ?>

           <option value="<?php echo $complemento['complemento'] ?>"><?php echo $complemento['complemento'] ?></option>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>
```

PHP:

```
$tipo = $_POST['tipo']; 
$nombre = $_POST['nombre_cotizar'];
$mail = $_POST['email_cotizar'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono_cotizar'];

$complementos = array();

foreach ($_POST['complementos'] as $complemento){
    $complementos [] = $complemento;
}

$resultado_complementos = implode(", ", $complementos);

$mensajeMail = "De: $nombre \nCorreo: $mail \nTeléfono: $telefono \n\nTipo: $tipo \n\nComplementos: $resultado_complementos \n";

mail($destino, "Presupuesto", $mensajeMail);

try {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Cotizar (Tipo, Adicionales, Nombre, Mail, Telefono) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $tipo, $resultado_complementos, $nombre, $mail, $telefono);
    $stmt->execute();
    if($stmt->affected_rows){
        $respuesta = array(
            'respuesta' => 'exito' 
        );
    } else{
        $respuesta = array(
            'respuesta' => 'error' 
        );
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $respuesta = array(
            'respuesta' => $e->getMessage() 
        );
}
die(json_encode($respuesta));
```

I want to add the option values in a string to save it on the db and send it via email

Comment: `var_dump($_POST['complementos'] );`

Comment: Make `$_POST['complementos']` an array via `name="complementos[]"`  in your `<select>`

Comment: Problem solved guys!! thanks

Comment: @Phil you should turn this comment into an answer because it's definitely a solution.

Comment: @Vincent it's already answered in the duplicate